# Docker error: The command returned a non-zero code: 137

Tags: docker, docker-compose, next.js

I am using a digital ocean droplet to deploy my webapp. I created a droplet and I have installed `Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701` and `docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c`. I used the same webapp on another droplet with same configurations and it was all right. I need to change droplet because I want to resize it to a smaller one, and they don't allow it for filesystem reasons.

I have this `Dockerfile`:

```
# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM node:16-alpine AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
COPY .env.local .env.local
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

# If using npm with a `package-lock.json` comment out above and use below instead
# COPY package.json package-lock.json ./ 
# RUN npm ci

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM node:16-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY .env.local .env.local
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during the build.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN yarn build

# If using npm comment out above and use below instead
# RUN npm run build

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM node:16-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during runtime.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

# You only need to copy next.config.js if you are NOT using the default configuration
# COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY .env.local .env.local
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size 
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY .env.local .env.local
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000
```

This is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.7"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      #- "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=my@email.com"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=acme.json"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"

  appName:
    build: repo-name/. 
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.casual_name.rule=Host(`casual_name.app`) || Host(`www.casual_name.app`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.casual_name.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.casual_name.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.casual_name.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
      # www -> https
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchallwww.rule=Host(`www.casual_name.app`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchallwww.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchallwww.middlewares=redirect-to-https@docker"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.http-catchallwww.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      # www -> non-www
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.www-redirect.redirectregex.regex=^https://www.casual_name.app/(.*)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.www-redirect.redirectregex.replacement=https://casual_name.app/$${1}"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.www-redirect.redirectregex.permanent=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchallwww.middlewares=www-redirect"
```

I am getting that error on the final step *[4/4] Building fresh packages...*.

The complete error log is `The command '/bin/sh -c yarn install --frozen-lockfile' returned a non-zero code: 137`

Do you have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: I am countering the same issue, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: I remember I switched to Digital ocean's App